# DB management in Docker

Tags: docker

I am new to the Docker development environment. In my JHipster Docker environment, I run into an error of "relation "" already exists" when I start the Docker image. This error occurs after the DB schema is changed. The following is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    foo-app:
        image: foo
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://foo-postgresql:5432/foo
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the applicationelasticsearch:9300
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    foo-postgresql:
        extends:
            file: foo.yml
            service: foo-postgresql
```

And the `foo.yml` file is the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
    foo-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/foo/postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=foo
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

At this point, I can drop DB tables since the application isn't up and the DB is. I, however, don't see it as a right approach of a DB management. I also can bring up the DB image with a command

```
docker run -i -t '<DB image name>' /bin/bash
```

I, however, can't access the DB with a command

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

What is a right way to manage a DB in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest because of the same problems you are facing I went with a cloud DB service (AWS RDS) instead of hosting docker containers for DB. I still use Docker DB container for local/qa environments because these environments do not need to be scalable.

For dev I throw both services (app/db) in a docker-compose.yml file and kick it off using a bash script. In the script I put a few sleep commands to ensure the db was up and ready, and then init the app after that. I'm using mysql container, and usually 40 seconds is plenty of time to ensure mysql service is up. Not a production ready situation, but I couldn't get a nice solution for figuring out if my db container was up and available.

In a production or HA environment with RDS the database is always available, so when a new docker container is added to the cluster there is no waiting for a dependent DB container as well.

Here's the script to start services and wait:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Use environment variable set in the .env file.
source ./.env

###Name the container and launch, Check docker-compose.yml ####
echo "Starting Docker containers ..."
CONTAINER=${CONTAINER_NAME}
docker-compose up -d

sleep 20
echo "..."
sleep 20

Continue with my app setup...
```